# What is custom URI handler in android?

Tags: security

I came across the term "Custom URI Handler" which is a bad practice in android security. Can anybody please tell what is custom URI handler? What are the security issues raised by custom URI handlers?

Comment: It'll be possible to give a much more useful explanation if you give a little more context about where you've seen the term and why you think it's a bad practice.

Comment: I don't know the context exactly. It is security perspective, the bad practices.       Is it custom a protocol like http?